# Proof by contraposition: a function is not one-to-one

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Prove that if $f:A \rightarrow B$, $g:B\rightarrow C$ and $g\circ f:A\rightarrow C$ is one-to-one, then $f:A\rightarrow B$ is one-to-one.

Here is my solution:

Proof by contraposition.

Let $x\in A$ and $y\in A$ and define $f$ as two functions from $x$ to $f(x)$ and from $y$ to $f(y)$ so that $f: x\rightarrow f(x)$ and $f:y \rightarrow f(y)$.

Consider the function $f:A\rightarrow B$ where $x \in A$ and $f(x) \in B$ as well as $y\in A$ and  $f(y) \in B$. Assume, however, that $x \ne y$. Then $f(x) \ne f(y)$. Therefore $f$ is not one-to-one.

As $g: B\rightarrow C$, it follows that

$g: f(x)\rightarrow g(f(x))$

$g: f(y)\rightarrow g(f(y))$

where $g(f(x)) \in C$ and $g(f(y))\in C$.

By function multiplication, $g(f(x))$ and $g(f(y))$ can be rewritten as $g\circ f(x)$ and $g \circ f(y)$ respectively. Since $f(x) \ne f(y)$, it follows that $g(f(x)) \ne g(f(y))$. Therefore $g$ is not one-to-one.

Because $f:A\rightarrow B$ is not one-to-one and $g:B\rightarrow C$ is not one-to-one, $g \circ f:A \rightarrow C$ is not one-to-one.

Thus, $f(x)=f(y)$ is only possible when $x=y$. Meaning $f:A\rightarrow B$ must be one-to-one in order for $g \circ f:A\rightarrow C$ to be one-to-one.

Is this an accurate proof? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 mistakes:

1: if $x\ne y\implies f(x)\ne f(y)$ then the function **is** one-to-one.

2: you assumed that $x\ne y\implies f(x)\ne f(y)$, you can't do this, you are trying to prove it

---

the proof goes like this:

now consider $x,y$ where $x,y\in A,\ x\ne y$. now consider the case where $g(f(x))\ne g(f(y))$, because $g\circ f$ is one-to-one it implies that $f(x)\ne f(y)$. now if $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ then $f(x)=f(y)$ but if $g\circ f$ is one-to-one we can find $\left(g\circ f\right)^{-1}$ such that $\left(\left(g\circ f\right)\circ\left(g\circ f\right)^{-1}\right)(x)=x$ so we should 
be able to find $x,y$ from $g\circ f$, which is impossible if $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$, thus the case where $x\ne y$ and $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ cant happened, and if $f(x)=f(y)$ then  $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ have to be true. thus if $x\ne y$ we have $f(x)\ne f(y)$.

and done